# Overriding default style for border makes my WPF window rounded

Tags: wpf, border, rounded-corners, cornerradius

I override borders **CornerRadius** as a default style in the **app.xaml** file (like below)

```
<Application x:Class="BorderCornerProblem.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="50"/>  
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and in the **MainWindow.xaml** file I have

```
<Window x:Class="BorderCornerProblem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">       
</Window>
```

the result is that the window has a black rounded corners.

My question then is how to define a **DefaultStyle** with **CornerRadius** set for **Border** that will not mess with my Window?

Comment: So you want to change some border styles but not all?

Comment: well, yes. I would like to have one style for all the borders I use **explicitly** in xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should *not* globally style `Borders`, they are everywhere.

Give the style a key and only reference it where needed.

Comment: I really don't like your answer but it looks like its sooo true :( DataGrid is also affected by my Borders Style. I'll do my own control wtih the propper style. Thanks for your help